# Setting default Asp.Net Session memory consumption?

Tags: asp.net, memory

Some while ago I found a web page explaining the default size of a session was 2048 kb, the minimum was 1 kb.

How can this be adjusted? And if some one has links regarding the subject I would be a happy camper :)

Sorry not for mentioning the IIS, but it is 7.0

Cheers

Comment: You should be avoiding session if at all possible.

Comment: What version of IIS are you using? Clarifying this may help you get a more targeted answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real limit set for it. It is simply objects stored in .Net. Standard Windows process limits apply. You can apply a global limit in IIS (AppPool settings).

There is however a consideration to make when you use ASP.Net State Service or SQL State Storage. The Session object must be serialized, sent to the store, retrieved and deserialized. This is a very expensive process. Therefore you want to limit the amount of data you store in Session.

If you use internal state storage then the Session is simply kept in memory (no overhead), but this approach usually doesn't scale well with web clusters.